# R, aggregate( ) using table( ) as a function

Tags: r

I have dataset that looks like this but much larger:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                         c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1),
                         c(1,2,2,2,3,3,1,2,1)))
data$X3<-factor(data$X3)
levels(data$X3)<-c("House","Barn","Pigsty")
```

I want to have a dataset with counts of "House," "Barn," and "Pigsty" by `X1` and `X2`. Imagine that X and Y are coordinates and that I want to count how many of each type of building I have at each coordinate.

I am doing:

```
agdata <- aggregate(data[,"X3"],by=list(data[,"X1"],data[,"X2"]),FUN=table)
```

If I ask to print `agdata` by using `head(agdata)`, it shows me the two coordinates and the three count variables for each level of `X3`:

```
  > head(agdata)
     Group.1 Group.2  x.House  x.Barn   x.Pigsty

   1       1       1       1      2        0    
   2       2       1       2      1        0    
   3       1       2       0      1        2
```

However, if I use View(agdata) I only see three variables `Group.1` ,`Group2` ,and `x`.

How can I get `aggregate` to give me a dataset in the format that I see when I use `head(agdata)`?

Comment: You probably mean `View(agdata)`, not `View(data)`, correct? It seems to me like the problem may lie more in `View` than in `aggregate`. Consequently, I am confused as to what exactly you are asking. `aggregate` *does* give you the data in the format you see when you type `head(agdata)`. Could you please edit your question to clarify?

Comment: I meant `View(agdata)`. The question is edited as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it using *dcast* from *reshape2* package:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data, X1+X2 ~ X3)
```